# setreg.exe for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I want to use setreg.exe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387700(VS.85).aspx) to disable the certificate revocation check. However, it's based on an older version of .NET than what I have. Microsoft says it's shipped with the older .net SDK, and when I download that, try to install, it says something like 'can't install SDK without .net 1.1'.

In the article linked it says for newer versions I should use SignTool, but SignTool does not appear to have the function I need .

Is it possible to either -

a) find a tool that can perform the function I need that doesn't need me to install the older .NET

b) get setreg.exe without downloading the SDK

or do I need to install the older .NET on my machine? And if the latter is the case, what do I need to do to install an older .NET? Will it overwrite my current .NET?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET frameworks are backwards compatible. Therefore if I have an application written in .NET 2; my .NET 4 framework is sufficient.

Either way there may be a caveat with a .NET 1.1 application as that was prior to the widely distributed .NET 2 framework.

The .NET 1.1 framework can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=262D25E3-F589-4842-8157-034D1E7CF3A3&displaylang=en) and will not overwrite any other .NET framework which you may have installed.

Comment: While .NET 2-4 are backwards compatible with previous versions, it stops at .NET 2.  To run an app that is based on .NET 1.1, you must install .NET 1.1.  Now, the to tool itself may not be a .NET app, just bundled with the SDK.  In which case extracting it as @therube suggestion would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I installed 1.1 and it worked fine. I just needed to know if it would affect other versions of .NET. Chose this one as correct as it's the answer I used personally but I imagine the other solutions would work fine as well.

Answer (score 5):

If you were to download '.NET Framework SDK Version 1.1', you could extract its contents.
Within you would find netfxsd1.cab.
Within that you will find 'FL_setreg_exe_____X86.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8' which is the setreg.exe you are looking for.  (Simply rename the file.  This is exactly the same as the version supplied with W2K.)

'setup.exe' is a SFX .CAB file.

So if you have a method to open .CAB files (again rename from .exe to .exe.cab) it is easy enough to open or you could use the tool, uniextract.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyid=9b3a2ca6-3647-4070-9f41-a333c6b9181d&displaylang=en

http://www.legroom.net/software/uniextract

Answer (score 2):

SETREG.EX_ came with Win2K (in the I386 directory) if you have that available.
(You would need to use the EXPAND.EXE command to expand SETREG.EX_ to SETREG.EXE.)